# How can I prevent a recirc pump from cross-feeding?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture, pump

I installed this recirc pump on tees between the supply lines. I have another one installed and it works great. For some reason on this install, when I open the cold water line it pulls hot water across the pump and I get lukewarm water instead of cold water. Is there anything I could install on the outlet side of the pump (or elsewhere) to encourage the cold water to flow before the hot water?

[image]

Comment: Are you using the cold water line to return hot water to the tank?

Comment: Any of these that use the cold water to return will push hot/warm/tepid water down the cold pipe. You'll have to wait for all that to clear before you get fresh cold water again.